# The relation with Perfect numbers , Triangular Numbers and Cyclops numbers

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers, triangular-numbers

Triangular Numbers are numbers going from $1,3,6,10,15,21,28$ and so on . These numbers can be formed like a triangle , so called triangular numbers.

Perfect numbers are numbers going in the pattern $1,6,28$ and so on . Perfect numbers are numbers whose sum of the factors equals twice the number .

Cyclops numbers is a number in binary notation which has $1$'s only and a $0$ exactly in the middle . For example -

$0$ is a cyclops number , in base $10$ it is $0$ only.

$101$ is a cyclops number , in base $10$ it is $5$ .

$11011$ is a cyclops number , in base $10$ it is $27$ .

Now there is an interesting relation between these $3$ types of numbers . I notice that every perfect number is some triangular number , as well every perfect number is exactly $1$ less than their corresponding cyclops numbers when changed to base $10$ .

Can anyone tell my how this relation actually comes?

Comment: even perfect numbers are $2^{p-1}\left(2^p-1\right)$

Comment: yeah that is also an observation but we have a proof for it

Comment: Why the downvote ? Is there anything wrong with the Question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that every even perfect number is of the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$. It is not hard to see that a cyclops number with $2n+1$ digits in its binary form is:
$$1111 \ldots 1 (2n+1 \text{ ones})-1000\ldots0(n \text{ zeroes})=(2^{2n+1}-1)-2^n=2^{2n+1}-2^n-1$$

Moreover, triangular numbers are of the form:
$$1+2+3+\ldots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

Now, notice that **for even perfect numbers**:
$$2^{p-1}(2^p-1)=\frac{2^p(2^p-1)}{2}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2} \quad (k=2^p)$$
$$2^{p-1}(2^p-1)-1 = 2^{2p-1}-2^{p-1}-1=2^{2n+1}-2^n-1 \quad(n=p-1)$$

Thus, we have proven your observation for even perfect numbers. However, the existence of odd perfect numbers greater than $1$ is unknown.

Comment: In the first sentence, I would say every *even* perfect number is of the form...

Answer (score 1):

As shown by [Haran](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/438557) in his answer, every *even* perfect number is *triangular*.

It is currently unknown if there is an odd perfect number.  However, it has not been proved that an *odd* perfect number *cannot* be triangular.  (See this [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/234528), and the answers contained therein, for more information.)